# Rails 6 form_with remote UJS, bind extra handler to select or submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-6.1

In my Rails app, I have a `form` for voting on various "post" titles. The form has one `select` element, and submits remotely to a `VotesController` using `rails-ujs`. I want to handle response the normal way, in the controller receiving the request, with `respond_to do |format|`.

One option is adding `{:onchange=>'$(this.form).submit();'}` to the `f.select` builder, as [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177962/rails-remote-form-and-select-on-change-not-working) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586774/rails-submit-via-ajax-when-drop-down-option-clicked) have suggested.

However, because form submit takes about 8 seconds, I'd like to add my own handler to either the `select` `onchange`, or the `form` `onsubmit` (which event doesn't matter to me) to

- disable all other forms on the same page
- show a modal saying why we're disabling the other forms
- only allow one "favorite" vote per user (downgrade previous votes on other titles)
- store some data attributes in the select for later handling

The issue i'm having is

- if I bind my extra handler to the select `change` event, i can fire a submit via native `rails-ujs`, but the browser asks me if I want to leave the current page. **I can solve this by adding my own AJAX call to my handler** , but I'm trying to use the default Rails controllers and `rails-ujs` to handle submit. I just want to add an extra handler to change the DOM before the slow response arrives.
- if I bind my extra handler to the form `submit` event, the form does not submit and the binding does not have any effect on elements in the DOM, although there are no console errors.

Here's my code:

```rb
# partial appears on PostsController#show
# there are several of these on the page, for voting on post titles

<%= form_with(model: @vote, url: naming_vote_path(naming_id: naming.id),
              method: :patch, local: false, id: "cast_vote_#{naming.id}",
              class: "naming-vote-form") \
              do |f| %>
  <%= f.select(:value, menu, {},
               { class: "form-control w-100",
                 # onchange: "this.form.submit();", # works but does not allow further bindings
                 data: { role: "change_vote", id: naming.id } }) %>
<% end %>
```

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {

    var change_vote_selects = function () {
      return $("[data-role='change_vote']");
    };

    var attach_bindings = function () {
      change_vote_selects().on("change", function (event) {
        var _this = $(this);
        var value = _this.val();
        var naming_id = _this.data("id");
        _haveVotesChanged = true;

        // If setting vote to 3.0, go through all the rest and downgrade any
        // old 3.0's to 2.0.  Only one 3.0 vote is allowed. Also disable all
        // the selects while the AJAX request is pending.
        if (value == "3.0") {
          change_vote_selects().each(function () {
            var _this2 = $(this);
            if (_this2.data("id") != naming_id && _this2.val() == "3.0") {
              _this2.val("2.0");
            }
            _this2.attr("disabled", "disabled");
          });
        }

        // modal printed in layout already, add text to it and activate
        $('#naming_ajax_progress_caption').empty().append(
          $("<span>").text(translations.show_namings_saving + "... "),
          $("<span class='spinner-right mx-2'></span>")
        );
        $("#naming_ajax_progress").modal('show');

        _this.parent().submit();
      });

      // Save initial value in case of error, when we'll need to revert.
      change_vote_selects().each(function (event) {
        var _this = $(this);
        _this.data("old_value", _this.val());
        _this.attr("disabled", null);
      });
    };

    // Alert the user if they haven't saved data.
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
      if (_haveVotesChanged && !_haveVotesBeenSaved)
        return translations.show_namings_lose_changes;
    }

    attach_bindings();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45002658/3357635), I need to fire a native rails-ujs submit on the form, to submit remotely.

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {

    var change_vote_selects = function () {
      return $("[data-role='change_vote']");
    };

    var attach_bindings = function () {
      change_vote_selects().on("change", function (event) {
        var _this = $(this);
        var value = _this.val();
        var naming_id = _this.data("id");
        _haveVotesChanged = true;

        // If setting vote to 3.0, go through all the rest and downgrade any
        // old 3.0's to 2.0.  Only one 3.0 vote is allowed. Also disable all
        // the selects while the AJAX request is pending.
        if (value == "3.0") {
          change_vote_selects().each(function () {
            var _this2 = $(this);
            if (_this2.data("id") != naming_id && _this2.val() == "3.0") {
              _this2.val("2.0");
            }
            _this2.attr("disabled", "disabled");
          });
        }

        // modal printed in layout already, add text to it and activate
        $('#naming_ajax_progress_caption').empty().append(
          $("<span>").text(translations.show_namings_saving + "... "),
          $("<span class='spinner-right mx-2'></span>")
        );
        $("#naming_ajax_progress").modal('show');

        nativeFormEl = _this.parent()[0]
        Rails.fire(nativeFormEl, 'submit')

      });

      // Save initial value in case of error, when we'll need to revert.
      change_vote_selects().each(function (event) {
        var _this = $(this);
        _this.data("old_value", _this.val());
        _this.attr("disabled", null);
      });
    };

    // Alert the user if they haven't saved data.
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
      if (_haveVotesChanged && !_haveVotesBeenSaved)
        return translations.show_namings_lose_changes;
    }

    attach_bindings();
  });
```